# How to prove uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Here is the example, which is said to be very easy but I have no idea about it.

$X_1...X_n$ are integrable and 
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\limsup_{n \to \infty}E[|X_n|I\{|X_n|\ge t|\}]=0$$
Show that $X_n, n\ge 1$ are uniformly integrable.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should your indicator function be ${\bf 1}_{\{|X_n| \geq t\}}$?

Comment: @nobody, yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $K > 0$ such that 
$$\sup_n E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K\}] \leq \varepsilon$$

The assumption $\lim_{t \to \infty}\limsup_{n \to \infty}E[|X_n|I\{|X_n|\ge t|\}]=0$ tells us that there exists $K_\infty > 0$ such that $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K_\infty\}] \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and hence there exists an $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$, $E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K_\infty\}] \leq \varepsilon$.

This leaves us to deal with the finitely many $n < N$. Since each $X_i$ is integrable, there is a $K_i$ such that $E[|X_i| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K_i\}] \leq \varepsilon$. So for $K \geq \max\{K_1, \dots, K_N, K_\infty\}$ 
$$E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K\}] \leq \varepsilon$$ for every $n$ which is the desired result.

Comment: That's neat! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Ah, one more question. I wonder why $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K_\infty\}] \leq \varepsilon$ implies that there exists an $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$, $E[|X_n| \mathbb{1}\{|X_n| > K_\infty\}] \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: I think this might be problematic since $\limsup a_n \le \varepsilon$ can't imply that there is an $N$ such that any $n \ge N, a_n \le \varepsilon$

Comment: @Heydude Sorry, there was a typo in my answer with an obvious fix. $\limsup a_n \leq \varepsilon/2$ certainly implies there is $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $a_n \leq \varepsilon$. I'm updating the answer now.