# If $\tau ^{(n)}\downarrow \tau $ then $\{X_{\tau ^{(n)}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, stochastic-analysis

Reading in the book of Bhattacharya and Waymire of probability theory I find the following assertion:

> Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in [0,T]}$ a right-continuous martingale adapted to a filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\in [0,T]}$, for $T>0$ finite, and $\tau $ an stopping time. Let $P_n:=\{k2^{-n}T:k\in\{0,\ldots ,2^n\}\}$ and define $\tau ^{(n)}:=\min\{s\in P_n: s-\tau\geqslant 0 \}$, then $\{X_{\tau ^{(n)}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable.

I cannot see why $\{X_{\tau ^{(n)}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable, the "proof" in the book state that

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|> \lambda ]}|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|)&=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[\tau ^{(n)}=(k+1)2^{-n}T]\cap [|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|>\lambda ]}|X_{(k+1)2^{-n}T}|)\\
&\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[\tau ^{(n)}=(k+1)2^{-n}T]\cap [|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|>\lambda ]}|X_{T}|)\\
&=\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|>\lambda ]}|X_{T}|)\to \operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau}|>\lambda ]}|X_{T}|)\tag1
\end{align*}
$$

However, from the above I dont see any reason about why $\{X_{\tau ^{(n)}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ must be uniformly integrable. To be uniformly integrable it must be the case that

$$
\lim_{\lambda \to +\infty }\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|> \lambda ]}|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|)=0\tag2
$$

The problem is that the convergence $\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|>\lambda ]}\to \mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau}|>\lambda ]}$ a.s. is not monotone in any sense, as far as I can see, so its neither the convergence

$$
\operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau ^{(n)}}|>\lambda ]}|X_{T}|)\to \operatorname{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[|X_{\tau}|>\lambda ]}|X_{T}|)\tag3
$$

So I cannot assert (2) from (1). Can someone enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: There is an equivalent definition of uniform integrability for a sequence of random variables where the sup in (2) is replaced with a limsup, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600387/how-to-prove-uniform-integrability). You have a real limit instead of a limsup so it works.